# Lync sends clipped text

Tags: mac, macos, ms-office

I use Lync in Mac OS El Capitan. I installed Lync 14.2.1. When I send some text to somebody, he gets this text as clipped. tail of chars are clipped. it is impossible to read "y" or "g". because they don't have tails. I tried to various font and font size but no change. how can I fix this ?

Comment: What kind of computer/OS is the recipient using? Does it happen only between the two of you or also if you send a message to other Lync users with the same OS as the user mentioned in the question?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with Lync 14.2.1 (150923) and El Capitan (10.11.2 (15C50)). It occurs only when sending messages to Lync for Windows (I'm not sure which version but one compatible with both Office 2010 and 2013). Mac to Mac messages look fine. The symptom is with line spacing (the vertical distance between lines of text) that causes text to be clipped and difficult to read.

I have done extensive testing to try to find the solution, by changing font sizes on both the sending side (Mac) and receiving side (Windows) to no avail. When I log in to my account on Lync 2010 (4.0.7577.4484) for Windows 7 through a Windows 7 VM, my messages look fine to recipients.

To conclude, Win-to-Win and Mac-to-Mac are fine, but Mac-to-Win is not, regardless of the font or font size selected on both ends.

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: exactly I have same problem.

Comment: Correct, AllInOne. My mistake. Sorry.